# Complex Queries using multiword synonyms in Solr Lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, solr4

Solr Versions tested: 4.7.0 and 5.5.0.

In solr, when I query for some text say "Artificial Intelligence AND NYC".
I want to have a functionality (on the Query side, not Indexing side) of  expanding the query to include the synonyms of the passed-in query too.

So in this case, query should be logically equivalent to

```
(summary:Artificial Intelligence summary:AI ) AND 
(summary:NYC summary:New York or summary:New York City)
```

But currently following is the expansion instead

```
((summary:Artificial summary:AI) summary:Intelligence) AND
(((summary:NYC summary:New summary:New) (summary:York summary:York) summary:City)
```

And that is obviously not what I want.

Some work on multi-word synonyms is being done in [1](https://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-synonyms/issues/12) but it is not in production yet! I tried to use the Hon Lucene parser. It works well with multi-word synonyms but it does not support handling operators in the query. See 
[issue here](https://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-synonyms/issues/12)

I can't find anything working well with multi-word synonyms on Solr yet and this is very surprising. Can someone share their experience on this?

1 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5379

2 - https://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-synonyms/